# How to use a named volume bind in a Docker compose using Docker for Windows with WSL2 (Windows 10 v.2004)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-volume

I want to mount a volume to share among different containers started in a docker. But I want to mount that volume in a especific folder, let's say: /home/myuser/durable.

I managed to do it in this way:

1. Define the docker volume in advance:

```
   docker volume create --driver local \
   --opt type=none \
   --opt o=bind \
   --opt device=/home/mysuser/durable \
   myOwnVolumeBind
```

2. Define docker-compose.yml and use the shared volume as external:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  node1:
    build: ./config/node1
    image: myImage
    hostname: host1
    environment:
       - ISC_DATA_DIRECTORY=/dur/node2
    volumes:
     - myOwnVolumeBind:/dur
     - ./config:/config
  node2:
    build: ./config/node2
    image: myImage
    hostname: host2
    environment:
       - ISC_DATA_DIRECTORY=/dur/node2
    volumes:
     - myOwnVolumeBind:/dur
     - ./config:/config
volumes:
  myOwnVolumeBind:
    external: true
```

The first time that I execute docker-compose up, it runs smoothly.

But the, if I stop the containers with docker-compose down and try to up them again, it fails saying the it can't mount the volume...

This is the sequence:

```
docker-compose up
```

-- Done and fine
then...

```
salva@ESXPS13JSALVADOR:~/projects/sharding$ docker-compose down
```

Stopping sharding_node2_1 ... done
Stopping sharding_node1_1 ... done
Removing sharding_node2_1 ... done
Removing sharding_node1_1 ... done
Removing network sharding_default

```
salva@ESXPS13JSALVADOR:~/projects/sharding$ docker-compose up
```

Creating network "sharding_default" with the default driver
Creating sharding_node1_1 ... error
Creating sharding_node2_1 ...

ERROR: for sharding_node1_1  Cannot start service node1: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/myOwnVolumeBind/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount /run/desktop/mnt/host/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu-20.04/46565b0cdfb27e1c6f9311ee05188e1104e98034a9b364fa3ae2db8076f54f93:/var/lib/docker/volumes/myOwnVolumeBind/_data, flags: 0x100Creating sharding_node2_1 ... error

ERROR: for sharding_node2_1  Cannot start service node2: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/myOwnVolumeBind/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount /run/desktop/mnt/host/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu-20.04/46565b0cdfb27e1c6f9311ee05188e1104e98034a9b364fa3ae2db8076f54f93:/var/lib/docker/volumes/myOwnVolumeBind/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory

ERROR: for node1  Cannot start service node1: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/myOwnVolumeBind/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount /run/desktop/mnt/host/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu-20.04/46565b0cdfb27e1c6f9311ee05188e1104e98034a9b364fa3ae2db8076f54f93:/var/lib/docker/volumes/myOwnVolumeBind/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory

ERROR: for node2  Cannot start service node2: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/myOwnVolumeBind/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount /run/desktop/mnt/host/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu-20.04/46565b0cdfb27e1c6f9311ee05188e1104e98034a9b364fa3ae2db8076f54f93:/var/lib/docker/volumes/myOwnVolumeBind/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

---

I don't know what's going on here. Why is it able to mount the volume the first time but not in the following.... by the way, it's not clear to my where is supposed to be the file: /var/lib/docker/volumes/myOwnVolumeBind/_data

Perhaps I'm doing it wrongly. My goal is being able to decide in which folder of my Ubuntu distribution  (WSL2) is going to be stored my durable data. If there is a better approach, please, let me know.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There have been a few bug fixes related to volumes on WSL 2 in the last couple of Docker Desktop Edge releases. Which version of Docker Desktop are you running?

Comment: Docker Desktop Community: 2.3.0.4 (46911)
Engine: 19.03.12